# What is the Golang equivalent to Java's javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException?

Tags: ssl, go

I'm trying to set up some logging/monitoring for a Golang application. I want to be alerted if an SSL handshake error occurs. In Java I looked for the string "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException". Is there an equivalent in Golang for when something goes wrong with an SSL handshake?

Comment: Yo can simply test it out. Just try some of the subpages of https://badssl.com which should definitely cause the SSL/TLS handshake to fail.

Comment: I believe the closest you may get is [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/e875fe42eee942c35cdecc7b4b5d4e762f47bade/src/crypto/tls/alert.go#L51).

Comment: Assuming an HTTPS server, set [*http.Server.ErrorLog](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) to something you can monitor. TLS errors contain the string "tls:".

Answer (score 1):

Golang has no exceptions, but funcs return errors. This code would set err if the handshake fails:

```
conf := &tls.Config{}
tlsCon, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "example.com:443", conf)
if err != nil { // err is set when handshake fails
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}
tlsCon.Close()
```